# How to use web2py auth to send emails via gmail

Tags: email, web2py

When setting up an E-Mail service in Web2Py like described [in the book](http://www.web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/08/emails-and-sms#Setting-up-email), and using the `auth` mailer

```
mail = auth.settings.mailer
```

does it mean that when I create an account using my gmail-address and password they will be used for logging in to the smtp-server, or do I still have to hardcode the password?

```
mail.settings.login = 'username:password'
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you must still set the `mail.settings.login` setting (though its value doesn't have to be hard coded in the app code -- it could be retrieved via `AppConfig` or an environment variable, for example).

Comment: By `environment variable` do you mean to check if user is logged in to google? I found [this chapter in the book](http://www.web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/09/access-control#SMTP-and-Gmail). Still don´t get it how to avoid storing the google-password in a file. Thanks!

Comment: No, I mean [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable). In Python, you would retrieve an environment variable via: `import os; os.environ.get('NAME_OF_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE')`.